# Delphi gone mad: Says TstringList.sorted is an "undeclared identifier"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

My code is exactly like the example in the help file:

```
myStrings := TStringList.Create;
myStrings.Sorted := True;
myStrings.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
```

The compiler tells me that both `sorted` and `Duplicates` are undeclared identifiers.

But, how can that be if it correctly reconizes the `TStringList.Create`? I have not redifined stringList classes any where else. It is a simple testing stub that has the absolute minimum components in order to test a specific tecnique...  `uses Classes, Windows and Dialogs` --in that order.

Comment: Where did you declare myStrings - can you share that code?

Comment: Function doSomeThing: boolean;
var
  myStrings: TStrings;
begin ...

Comment: The Create does not fail because TStringlist is defined in Classes. The identtifiers are undefined for TStrings (the type of myStrings).

Answer (score 9):

I think that myString is declared as TStrings

```
var myStrings: TStrings; //From second Comment
```

Declare that as TStringList

```
var myStrings: TStringList;
```

Comment: Or type-cast:  TStringList(myStrings).Sorted := ...;